# Python Pandas Printing Series when adding one Column based on another Column

Tags: python, pandas

Adding one column based on another column value .. as below example -- Every time i do that, i am getting series of number, what i am doing wrong here ?

```
ROW1,ROW2
Almost_Cooking,1001
Almost_Cooking,1008
Almost_Cooking,1016
Almost_Cooking,1029
Almost_Games,978
Almost_Games,986
Almost_Games,993
Almost_Games,996
```

code

```
import pandas as pd
lf = pd.read_csv(r'test.csv')

dff3 = lf.groupby(["ROW1"])["ROW2"].sum().reset_index()

Tried this same -- dff2 = lf.groupby('ROW1')['ROW2'].agg('sum')
```

Output is like this in Intellij ---

```
                 ROW1                                               ROW2
0       Almost_Cooking  1001100810161029105011111912012012313714719619...
1         Almost_Games  1006103310351042124125142145152153160173191942...
```

Instead of Series, i need summation of whole numbers.

Comment: did you check the datatype for row2 ?

Comment: In your second column, you probably have strings and not only numerical data.

Comment: @Corralien - Thanks very much ... Yes there is strings and numerical data...